# How to autologin in debian 10?

Tags: debian, boot, gdm3, autologin

I just installed  debian 10, but it wants able to make it autologin into mate after the boot, Im using gdm and try to edit the

```
 /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf
```

Uncomented the autologin and user lines but this makes the system simple stopped to both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use lightdmcfg -- GUI to configure LightDM display manager
LightDM Configurator (lightdmcfg) is a program to configure LightDM display manager.
Features:
- session selection

- enable/disable guest session
- autologin setting
- theme change
- hide/show user list

Install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fsnow/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install lightdmcfg
```

Documentation for lightdmcfg - `/usr/share/doc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.gz`
There are a bunch of settings.
Dependency (if needed) [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libs/gir1.2-polkit-1.0) and [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/uk/trusty/all/python-xdg/download).

Author - FSnow

Forum (on russian) - http://forum.runtu.org/index.php/topic,2586.0.html