# Debian 10 auto login - lightdmcfg repo issue

Tags: debian, lightdm

I am following along with  [How to autologin in debian 10?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/536353/how-to-autologin-in-debian-10). As the snip shows, this ends up pointing to a Ubuntu repo which my installation of Debian 10 fails to find.

What's the fix for this?

```
 root@hpdb:/home/stephen# add-apt-repository ppa:fsnow/ppa

  More info: https://launchpad.net/~fsnow/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
 Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

 gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp64_53n2s/pubring.gpg' created
 gpg: /tmp/tmp64_53n2s/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
 gpg: key A3C2E0B93BF8E342: public key "Launchpad PPA for FSnow" imported
 gpg: Total number processed: 1
 gpg:               imported: 1
 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
 root@hpdb:/home/stephen# sudo apt-get install lightdmcfg  
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 E: Unable to locate package lightdmcfg
 root@hpdb:/home/stephen# apt update
 Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
 Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease                    
 Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease      
 Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
 Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release   
 Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fsnow/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
 Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fsnow/ppa/ubuntu focal Release
   404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `lightdmcfg` accept only `precise` or `trusty` codenames.

The package is outdated it is not recommended to install it on debian.

To answer the question  :

The `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.`  error can be solved by:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A3C2E0B93BF8E342
```

[Fsnow](https://launchpad.net/~fsnow/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages)